# After RESTART every new Safari window no longer reflects its DEFAULT appearance. How fix this? High Sierra MBP

Tags: safari, settings

OS X 10.13.3 Safari how set default window size & position (NOT FINDER)

Comment: I think Safari saves your window size on quit.

Comment: Thx, Josh! Of corse I'll try it BUT I have it to always re-open windows I have left open. So, I quit or SHUT DOWN ... then when Safari is re-opened, with older windows open (if any), I go MENU/FILE/NEW WINDOW (or CMD-N) how can I ensure that my preferred default size, shape & position window – blank/empty, or some chosen www in Prefs – opens as the "new window"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a little late but you can set a default zoom for all websites. Safari>Preferences>General>Page Zoom. Then there is an option in the bottom right that says "When visiting other sites". You can also set the zoom for specific pages.

Comment: 1. "Safari>Preferences>General>Page Zoom" is not the proper path to Page Zoom. 2. The question is about how to set default window size and position for Safari, which is not at all the same as or relevant to Page Zoom.

Answer (score 3):

A New window will be the same size as the last one you opened, & will align just below & right of the last window [standard window **cascading**] - if the previous window was 'new' this session. 
If the is insufficient space to fit the next new window below-right, then it will open aligned under the menu bar, the same distance right & start cascading again from there.

If the last new window was reopened from a previous session, then the sizing will match, but the position will be aligned to the menu bar.

afaik, this is not changeable.

Comment: Thank you, Tetsujin. IOW there is no way under current OS X to SET DEFAULT of new window attributes. Alas. Why would Apple think this was somehow important to eliminate from Safari prefs ... grrr.BTW your avatar-icon here is a nice design! And since I was just browsing images of Marvel's Dr. Strange comic book character your icon design reminds me of one of his magical spell gestures!!  ;–)

Comment: I don't recall any browser having a default window setting & I've been using Macs since System 6 ;) The avatar, btw, is from [Tim Minchin's 'Storm'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhGuXCuDb1U&ab_channel=stormmovie) Well worth 10 minutes of your time ;)